# Link to a page and trigger toggle event on div

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery to toggle a hidden (by default) div on page 1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

What I need to be able to do is link to page 1 from page 2 as well as open the hidden div in the same event.

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on a simple execution of this? Cheers!

Comment: Not clear what's meant by "link to". Surely if the user is clicking a link it doesn't matter what this page does after the click? Or do you mean that after they click link on page 2, they go to page 1 and the toggle happens?

Comment: Hi Greg, sorry for the confusion! Yes - they click a link on page 2 that opens page 1 and triggers the toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on page 2:

```
<a href="page1.html?panel_open=1"> click me </a>
```

on page 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // parse the query params
    var url_params = (window.location.search.substr(1)
      .split('&')
      .reduce(function(prev, curr) { 
          curr = curr.split('='); 
          if( curr.length > 1 ) { prev[curr.shift()]=curr.join('='); }
          return prev; 
      }, {}));

    if( url_params.panel_open ) {
        // if "panel_open" was passed in the URL, then open the panel
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    }
});
```

Edit: made a couple of minor changes in the query string parsing code above, to improve robustness in a few edge cases.

---

**Update**

Older browsers (including IE8) don't support the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.  So, here's a version of the code above that doesn't use that function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    var url_params = {};
    for (; parts.length ;) {
        var curr = parts.shift().split('=');
        if (curr.length > 1) {
            url_params[curr.shift()] = curr.join('=');
        }
    }

    if( url_params.panel_open ) {
        // if "panel_open" was passed in the URL, then open the panel
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for the contribution Lee. It doesn't seem to work in IE8, (object doesn't support this property or method) any ideas why?

[http://goo.gl/LRMvX](http://goo.gl/LRMvX)

Comment: the [`reduce()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is part of ECMAScript-5, but it's not supported by IE8 (nor by many other older browsers).  You can add support for it by including [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) in your page.  Or you can rewrite the parsing to work without it.  (I'll add an update that doesn't use it).

Comment: Thanks Lee, I have managed some success with es5-shim. This line in the documentation however does not fill me with smiles "It is not likely to behave as advertised in a large cross-section of browsers". I would love to see your update that doesn't require it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since events don't persist across pages I would recommend using another strategy like passing a parameter or hash link in the query string that the receiving page can interpret and open the div in question.

Comment: or a hidden field that no brainy guy will not be able to modify