# Link to a page and open a toggles with the links

Tags: php, hyperlink, toggle

I am trying to have a links on my home page that will link to a service page that contains multiple toggles.  I would like to open a specific toggle based on what link they choose on the home page.

Here is what I have on my home page for the link to the service page (I know I will need something after /services to tell the function to open the toggle):

```
<a href="http://www.debdweb.com/test/services">Go to Service 1 (open)</a>
```

Here is what I have on my service toggle page for one of the toggles:

```
<div class="service-box">
    <div class="separator8"></div>
    <ul class="service_list">
        <li>
            <h6><a href="#Service1" class="toggle-link tog1">Service 1</a></h6>
            <div class="sub-text" id="Service1">
                Curabitur faucibus magna at leo commodo sed cursus dui posuere.
                Praesent ornare, leo et aliquet tempus, orci orci luctus leo.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what I think I need is the function to put in the header to open the 'passed in' toggle on link.  I have tried various functions but I am not so good at that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Format your hyperlinks like this:

`<a href="http://www.debdweb.com/test/services?id=1">Go to Service 1 (open)</a>`

And take the number from the URL with `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @ariefbayu, When I make the link look like the above I get a 404 errors, should it be ?id=1  rather than /id=1  ?  Also, can you tell me how to get the id of each toggle with $_GET['id'], do I need a function for that?  Can I see it in firefox with a plugin?

Comment: @ariefbayu, I just want to add that I am trying to get the toggle to open when I link to it as it is closed by default when that page is gone to by the main menu.  All of the toggles on this page will be closed by default.  I just want a specific one to be open when gone to from these special links.

Comment: @ariefbayu, I have tried doing some things done in this question but I didn't have any luck making it work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763129/link-to-a-page-and-trigger-toggle-event-on-div.  Here is the link to where I have been playing around with this:  http://www.debdweb.com/test/  Thanks!!